# What happened to GOOG-stock? Why isn't it 1.000 USD?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I just try to understand what happened to the Google stock. In October 2013 many newspapers wrote that the GOOG stock reached 1.000 USD.

When I now look at [the charts for this share](https://www.google.com/finance?q=goog) and scroll back to October 2013 the value back then was at about 500 USD.

So, what happened to the Google stock? I am sure when I looked at the charts in October, they displayed 1.000 USD, but now they don't. Can the values be changed at a future date? If yes, why?

Comment: Google had a two-for-one stock split recently.

Comment: Ah, ok. So now everyone who had one share now has two with the half price?

Comment: http://blogs.marketwatch.com/thetell/2014/04/02/google-investors-are-about-to-get-goog-and-googl-shares-in-stock-split/ may be useful to read about the split.

Comment: Essentially yes, although in this case it is a bit more complicated because Google introduced a new class of shares without voting rights. Every owner of a GOOG share at the split date got an additional share without voting rights, thus having twice as many shares (each valued at roughly half price).

Comment: Adding to that: Because charts should be consistent, charts are backward adjusted for stock splits

Answer (score 6):

The stock split, it is similar to what happened to Apple a little while back. When Google split 2 to 1, it means that each share holder got 2 shares for each 1 share they had and each share was 1/2 the price.